# Azure Mqtt Direct Connection

Tags: azure

Am working on MQTT with GSM Module previously done with HiveMq Server which is working perfectly by ref of [doc](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html). I have done Publish and Subscribe through `broker.hivemq.com` Port `1883`.

Now Presently I am on Azure. So many Queries are there in these Proposal

As MQTT Packet is Unique, I guess i can connect in similar way as like hivemq but am unable to find IP address for Azure where i found by my guess is `XXXXXX.azure-devices.net` and port `8883`. Is Correct?

I got Device ID key in this format `dF8vP17DxCwG8IRccXXXXXXkIrCVfWIC7qmcM`. Is it Password and should I provide Cert. also if yes what are they.

Is Username is `{iothubname}`?

After getting required Parameters above, Can I send MQTT packet Directly following this [document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html). If not Can you Please describe

Am having Connection string {} and Endpoint what are they?

To create Topic `messages/events/TOPIC`. Is this correct?

Really Confused with bunch of Doubts to communicate my device (GSM Module) with Azure.

Thanks & Regards
kishore D

Answer (score 0):

From [Using the MQTT protocol directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly):

> For the `ClientId` field, use the deviceId.
>
> For the Username field, use `{iothubhostname}/{device_id}/api-version=2016-11-14`, where `{iothubhostname}` is the full CName of the IoT hub.
>
> For example, if the name of your IoT hub is *contoso.azure-devices.net* and if the name of your device is *MyDevice01*, the full Username field should contain:
>
> ```
> contoso.azure-devices.net/MyDevice01/api-version=2016-11-14
> ```
>
> For the Password field, use a SAS token. The format of the SAS token is the same as for both the HTTPS and AMQP protocols:
>
> ```
> SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}
> ```

Azure IoT Hub is much more than an MQTT broker and doesn't really give you complete control over the protocol. A Mosquitto Docker container running on [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) may be a better solution if protocol control is key and we're looking at a hobbyist project. For the *cold path* you can store telemetry data in [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction).

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Hi Snobu,

      Am very happy for your response. 
1. How we can get Expiry Number? 2. Does this work as per document " http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html ". 3. If we can connect through MQTT packet by above doc, Does IP is correct "XXX.azure-devices.net" and port "8883".

Thanks in advance

kishor D

Comment: Yes, MQTT is implemented as Oasis MQTT, not Microsoft MQTT :)   address and port are correct, it accepts MQTT over TLS (MQTTS). Not sure what you mean by _expiry number_.

Comment: Hiii, SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}. what is this expiry in SAS?

Comment: Does api-version is same for user name

Comment: Is there any difference in packet format with MQTTS compared with MQTT

Comment: Advance Thanks for helping me

Comment: MQTTS = MQTT over TLS, same protocol but over a TLS encrypted channel. Think HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Am really sorry for disturbing you this many times. Please don't mind.

Comment: I have consulted my client. He implemented in Event Hub "messages/events" for every periodic intervals my device should be in listening mode will receive  notifications from cloud-device message. Here the problem comes my device dosen't know URL but inhand parameters we had is "Connection string","Endpoint". Can you please help in connection mechanism followed by my Device.(Mydevice is GSM Module).

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. If cloud-to-device and device-to-cloud messaging over MQTT is your desired outcome just follow the IoT hub documentation to implement both, or use the device SDK (there's an Arduino Cortex M0 compatible MQTT sample as well).